# Oracle DB get wierd errors

Tags: php, ajax, oracle, xampp, oracle10g

i have the next stored-procedure:

```
create or replace procedure generate_tables_for_project
as
begin
execute immediate 'create table farmers (email nvarchar2(30) PRIMARY KEY, fname nvarchar2(30), lname nvarchar2(30), password nvarchar2(30),  farmname nvarchar2(30), region nvarchar2(30), address nvarchar2(30) )';
execute immediate 'create table ISRAELLOCATIONS (region nvarchar2(30), regionID number(2) PRIMARY KEY )';
execute immediate 'create table product (name nvarchar2(30), productID number(2) PRIMARY KEY )';
execute immediate 'create table sub_product (name nvarchar2(30), sub_productID number(3) PRIMARY KEY , product_id number(2) REFERENCES product( productID))'; EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN IF SQLCODE = -955
THEN
raise_application_error(-20001, 'Tables Exist!!!');--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Data already exist!!!');
END IF;
end  generate_tables_for_project;
```

Now, when i activate the procedure in the SQLdeveloper its ok, tables will created.
But i i activate again i suppose to get only  -955 tables exist error.
But i also get the errors:

```
ORA-20001: Tables Exist!!!
ORA-06512: at "HR.GENERATE_TABLES_FOR_PROJECT", line 11
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

The ORA-20001 error is the error i raised for 0955 so this is fine,
but what are the two other?!

Thanks!

Comment: The other two are not errors. ORA 06512 is just the identifier for messages in the error stack that are related to the top-level exception. You only need to handle the actual error at the top of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Other two error is because there is an error on `HR.GENERATE_TABLES_FOR_PROJECT` procedure and error is in line no 2.

Comment: This is the procedure, what is the error in the create statment?

Comment: you don't have error on create statement. but the table created on that statement fails due to table exists. And these are actually an error stack to guide you to the exact point that have erred.

Comment: @ Shariar Imtiaz If there is error because of table exists so there is suppose only 955 error, so how i handle the addition error 6512?

Comment: It's not really an additional error - ORA-06512 is simply the identifier for a series of related messages issued at different levels of Oracle for the actual error at the top of the stack. You just have to handle the top-level exception.

Answer (score 0):

It shows the error stack, does not mean that you have more errors; for example:

```
    SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_error IS
  2  BEGIN
  3      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Error 1');
  4  EXCEPTION
  5      WHEN OTHERS THEN
  6          raise_application_error(-20002, 'Error 2');
  7  END;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec test_error
BEGIN test_error; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:  
ORA-20002: Error 2
ORA-06512: at "SIUCONTAB.TEST_ERROR", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: Ok, so howni can handle this exception?

Comment: I don't think you can; [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:195612348072) is an old discussion about that. Can't you avoid raise_application_error by using dbms_output or any other way of logging?

Comment: Its good, but if work with `dbms_output.put_line( sqlerrm );` i cant catch the 955 exception @Aleksej